# Elements of Relative layout stuck on the top left corner when I set layouts dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-relativelayout

I have coded relative layout and other elements dynamically in a Fragment file. I have been struggling in the issue that every element is stuck on the top left corner even though I have tried `.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM)`
and `.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW , id)`.

I feel that `addRule` doesn't affect my code at all.

Could some body help me out?

The Activity contains Fragment:

```
Fragment fragment = new RadioButtonFragment();
fragment.setArguments(args);
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container1,fragment);
ft.commit();
```

That Activity's XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container">
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

The Fragment I am talking about:

```
public class RadioButtonFragment extends Fragment {

    public RadioButtonFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d("onCreateFragment", "onCreate is called.");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_radio_button, container, false);

        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.relativelayout_radio_button);
        if(relativeLayout == null)
            Log.d("relativeLayoutError", "relativeLayout is null");

        String[] choices = {"choice1", "choice2", "choice3", "choice4", "choice5"};

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );

        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(relativeParams);

        // text view
        TextView questionTextView = new TextView(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );

        questionTextView.setText("this is the text of the question");
        textViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
        questionTextView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        int qViewId = 1;
        questionTextView.setId(qViewId);

        relativeLayout.addView(questionTextView);

        // for multiple choice
        // create scroll view
        ScrollView sv = new ScrollView(getActivity());

        // make radio button group
        RadioGroup rg = new RadioGroup(getActivity());
        rg.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        int number = 5;
        // i = 1 is question, 2, is previous button and 3 is next button
        for (int i = 4; i < number + 4; i++) {
            RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(getActivity());
            rdbtn.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 300));
            rdbtn.setId(i);
            rdbtn.setText(choices[i-4]);
            rg.addView(rdbtn);
        }
        sv.addView(rg);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams radioGroupViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        radioGroupViewParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, questionTextView.getId());

        relativeLayout.addView(sv);

        // set on click method
        rg.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
                RadioButton radioButton = getView().findViewById(checkedId);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), radioButton.getText(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

        RelativeLayout bottomRelativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams buttomRelativeParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
        );
        buttomRelativeParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);
        relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(buttomRelativeParams);
        relativeLayout.addView(bottomRelativeLayout);

        // create previous button
        Button previousButton = new Button(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams previousButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        previousButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        previousButton.setText("previous");

        bottomRelativeLayout.addView(previousButton);

        // create next button
        Button nextButton = new Button(getActivity());
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams nextButtonParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        nextButtonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        nextButton.setText("next");

        bottomRelativeLayout.addView(nextButton);

        Log.d("endOfAdd radio", "endOfAdd radio");

        return v;
    }
}
```

XML file of the Fragment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/relativelayout_radio_button"/>
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Set gravity to your LayoutParams object like this:

```
bottomRelativeLayout.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL;
```